# Why does an interface get emitted at the IL level as an "abstract interface"?

Tags: c#, .net, clr, roslyn, cil

I've been trying to learn more about the CLR and while doing so noticed that the following interface in C# will be compiled to IL that contains some kind of "abstract interface".

Given that declaring an interface as abstract in C# is not valid, what does it mean to allow an abstract interface at the IL level? Initially I wondered if this was how the runtime internally represents an interface, by declaring an abstract *class* thus preventing it being new-ed up.

It does appear to be following this idea, as shown by the `.class`. However, following that is `interface`. So the idea of needing to actually create an abstract *class* appears to be moot when the runtime already seems to support the concept of an interface.

This leads me to a couple of questions:

1. What is the purpose of the abstract interface, and why is an abstract interface valid at the IL level?
2. Why is `.class` *and* `interface` necessary, and why is this valid at the IL level?
3. If the runtime supports the concept of an interface, why is the `.class` or `abstract` required at all?

C#:

```
public interface IExample
{
    void SomeMethod(int number);
}
```

IL:

```
.class interface public auto ansi abstract IExample
{
    // Methods
    .method public hidebysig newslot abstract virtual 
        instance void SomeMethod (
            int32 number
        ) cil managed 
    {
    } // end of method IExample::SomeMethod

}
```

Comment: The mapping from a language syntax to metadata attributes is not always obvious.  In general the CLR allows more and the language designer chooses what he wants to use.  In this specific case, the C# compiler simply follows the metadata rule stipulated in Ecma-335, section II.22.37: "23. An Interface shall have Flags.Abstract = 1".  Keep that spec handy, you'll have a use for it when browsing MSIL.

Comment: That's an interesting extract thanks, just reading it now. It doesn't give the *reason* for that decision though.

Comment: That is the nice thing about a *rule*, you don't have to worry about what it might mean if you don't follow the rule ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you look at how [metadata](http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/3/3/733ad403-90b2-4064-a81e-01035a7fe13c/ms%20partition%20ii.pdf) (PDF) is defined at the IL level, *all* types are introduced by a `.class` header (even value types).

`interface` is described as a "Type semantic attribute" (10.1.3) and is used to distinguish whether what is being defined is, indeed, an interface, as opposed to an abstract class in which all members are abstract.

`abstract` is described as a "Inheritance attribute" (10.1.4) and specifically means the type cannot be instantiated.

That covers the intended meanings. As to why they're *necessary* (i.e. why `interface` doesn't automatically *imply* `abstract`), I believe it was done to make everything *explicit* at this level. Since you don't often have to write IL yourself, having some overlap between some of these flags isn't harmful.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! I agree, an interface probably doesn't imply `abstract` specifically so it can be explicit. +1 for the link as well. It's called Partition II, is this an extract from  the ECMA spec or another series of documents?

Comment: @user9993 - here's a [page full of the standards](https://www.visualstudio.com/license-terms/ecma-c-common-language-infrastructure-standards/). The document previously linked to is part of the "Microsoft Implementation Specific Versions" set.

Comment: @hoodaticus - making everything explicit offers an additional bonus - it leaves things more open to extension. The fact that they managed to introduce generics (without Java's type erasure) demonstrates that explicitly stating what could otherwise be "assumed" is a good way to go.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - well AMEN to that!  Every time I have to use Java generics - which is daily, my soul fills with hate.